# When to use regression trees/forests?

Tags: machine-learning, regression, svm, random-forest, decision-tree

As I was looking for a fine regression algorithm for my problem. I found out one can do that with simple decision trees as well, which is usually used for classification. The output would be something like:

[image: taken from otexts.org]

The red *noise* would be the prediction states of such a tree or forest.

Now my question is, why at all to use this method, when there are alternatives, that really try to figure out the underlying equation (such as the famous *support vector machines* SVM). Are there any positive / unique aspects, or was a regression tree more a nice-to-have-algorithm?

Comment: This question might have a bigger chance of getting an answer if you asked it [here](http://stats.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 2):

The image you posted conveys a smooth function of `y` in `x`. A regression tree is certainly not the best technique to estimate such a function and I probably wouldn't use SVMs either. This looks like a good application for splines, e.g., by using a GAM (generalized additive model).

A regression tree on the other hand is a handy tool if you haven't got such smooth functions and if you don't know which explanatory variable will have which effect on the response. It will be particularly useful if there are jumps in the response or interactions - especially if the jump points and interaction patterns are not known in advance.